# Как использовать JS библиотеки без NodeJS

Tags: javascript

В настоящее время, куда не глянь, любая полезная библиотека подключается к проекту npm install ... Но вот как быть, если в качестве сервера используется не нода, а, например, Golang? С некоторыми крупными библиотеками можно обойтись простым подключением ее в тег script на страницу, но многие либы не удается найти просто js файлом. Например, есть необходимость подключить к проекту [vue-native-websocket](https://github.com/nathantsoi/vue-native-websocket). Как с этим быть? Возможно мой вопрос глупый и я не понимаю каких то базовых вещей, но как с этим поступают фронтендеры, которые разрабатывают без nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необязательно использовать `NodeJS` в качестве сервера, он всего лишь позволяет запускать `JS` вне браузера. Обычно он необходим для сборки, например с помощью `Webpack`, `Gulp`, `Grunt`.

`NPM` - в свою очередь выступает менеджером пакетов, который скачивает файлы библиотек, возможно с исходниками, которые затем собираются тем же `webpack`.

Всё это необходимо для того, чтобы подключать и собирать только нужные вам функции, а не тащить тяжеловесные библиотеки "ради одной кнопки".

Поищите курсы в интернете, посмотрите что такое ES5, ES6 и т.д., воспользуйтесь `import` или `require`, соберите проект c `Webpack'ом` всё это гораздо удобнее, чем писать `script` теги и скачивать библиотеки вручную.

Comment: Но насколько я понимаю, webpack это тоже нодовская тема

Comment: ну это как раз-таки `JS` библиотека, которая запускается с помощью `NodeJS`, но как написал Stranger in the Q, запускается только один раз

Answer (score 1):

Сервер тут не причем. Клиентский код это отдельная портянка, да собирается она при помощи `node.js`, но один раз и на машине разработчика(или системой сборки, тут это не важно), а сервер-сервером. У меня вообще например бэкэнд на `java`, и что теперь не использовать библиотеки? =)

Потом, совершенно не обязательно все собирать в один bundle, можно подключать скрипты как обычно, тегами `script`, большинство уважающих себя и своих пользователей библиотек поддерживает все способы подключения.